# How to avoid a join using NHibernate 2.1 per table inheritance

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance

I'm doing some per table inheritance and all is working great- but I'm noticing that when I want the base entity (base table data) NHProf is showing a left outter join on the child entity / (related table)

How can I set the default behavior to only query the needed data - for example: When I want a list of parent elements (and only that data) the query only returns me that element.

right now my mapping is similar to the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="FormBase, ClassLibrary1" table="tbl_FormBase">
    <id name="BaseID" column="ID" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="ImportDate" column="ImportDate" type="datetime" not-null="false" />
    <joined-subclass table="tbl_Form" name="Form, ClassLibrary1">
      <key column="ID"/>
      <property name="gendate" column="gendate" type="string" not-null="false" />
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the example where I want all the data back vs ONLY the parent entity is shown below:

```
    Dim r As New FormRepository()
    Dim forms As List(Of Form) = r.GetFormCollection().ToList()



    Dim fbr As New FormBaseRepository()
    Dim fb As List(Of FormBase) = fbr.GetFormBaseCollection().ToList()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's called "implicit polymorphism" and it's a rather nice (albeit unwanted in your case :-) ) feature provided by Hibernate. When you query a list of base objects, the actual instances returned are of the actual concrete implementations. Hence the left join is needed for Hibernate to find out whether particular entity is a FormBase or a Form.

**Update** (too big to fit in comment):
The general issue here is that if you were to trick Hibernate into loading only the base entity you may end up with inconsistent session state. Consider the following:

1. `Form` instance (that is persisted to both `form_base` and `form` tables) was somehow loaded as `FormBase`.
2. You've deleted it.
3. During flush Hibernate (which thinks we're dealing with `FormBase` and thus is blissfully unaware that there are 2 tables involved) issues a `DELETE FROM form` statement which throws an exception as FK is violated.

Implicit polymorphism exists to prevent that from happening - `Form` is **always** a `Form`, never a `FormBase`. You could, of course, use "table-per-hierarchy" mapping where everything is in the same table and thus no joins are needed but you'll end up with (potentially) a lot of NULL columns and - ergo - inability to specify not-null on children's properties.

All that said, if this is **REALLY** a huge performance issue for you (which it normally shouldn't be - presumably it's an indexed join), you could try using a native query to just return `FormBase` instances.

Comment: Ahh ... - is there another approach to this inheritance problem that will keep my base table separate if I query for that entity and not the child? (right now each child element has its own table)

Comment: I've updated my answer above - too much stuff to fit in comment

Comment: Well i don't think it's a huge issue in my POC currently but this base class is inherited by almost 12 other classes in my production application ... so i'm a little worried (maybe I shouldn't be as you mentioned -- each would be an indexed join)

Comment: 12, huh? :-) 12 left joins might be a bit concerning on large tables; you should actually measure the performance before taking any drastic steps, though. One possible approach (which may or may not work depending on your needs) is to mix the table-per-concrete-class and table-per-subclass strategies: https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/inheritance.html This will only make sense if your hierarchy has multiple levels; won't work for 12 horizontal subclasses.